# How to do required-if in Angular Reactive Forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form and based on the property `fooRequired` I want to set the field to be required or not.

I can't change that because it set at initial. so what can I do?

```
fooRequired = false;

form = new FormGroup({
 foo: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
});

toggle() { this.fooRequired = !this.fooRequired; }
```

Comment: Have you tried re-initializing `form`, in `ngOnChanges` if the `fooRequired`'s value changed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following will do the trick:

```
toggle() {
  this.fooRequired = !this.fooRequired;
  this.form.controls.foo.setValidators(this.fooRequired ? null : [Validators.required]);
  this.form.controls.foo.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Here, based on the `fooRequired` boolean, the validators are set or removed. Finally, the new form control settings are updated.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a custom function that is gonna be responsible for adding or removing the `Validators`

```
export function conditionalValidator(
  predicate: BooleanFn,
  validator: ValidatorFn,
  errorNamespace?: string
): ValidatorFn {
  return formControl => {
    if (!formControl.parent) {
      return null;
    }
    let error = null;
    if (predicate()) {
      error = validator(formControl);
    }
    if (errorNamespace && error) {
      const customError = {};
      customError[errorNamespace] = error;
      error = customError;
    }
    return error;
  };
}
```

Then you can use it inside you form control:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  myEmailField: [
    "",
    [
      // some normal validatiors
      Validators.maxLength(250),
      Validators.minLength(5),
      Validators.pattern(/.+@.+\..+/),
      // custom validation
      conditionalValidator(
        // depends on fooRequired value
        () => this.fooRequired,
        Validators.required,
        "illuminatiError"
      )
    ]
  ]
});
```

Finally you can toggle the value of `fooRequired` and see the result:

```
  toggle() {
    this.fooRequired = !this.fooRequired;
    this.myForm.get("myEmailField").updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

Here is [a live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conditional-validators-3rd-workaround-5-custom-m-ama5cn?file=src/app/app.component.ts) to help you with implementing the above answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `setValidator()` and `updateValueAndValidity()` for your foo form control based on the fooRequired variable. These two functions will update the validation dynamically.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-setvalidators-jec7jo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

More to read:
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/how-to-add-validators-dynamically-using-setvalidators-in-angular/